# Change light switch on Supernova E3 Pure (Specialized AWOL Evo)

Tags: dynamo, specialized-bikes

I bought a second hand Specialized AWOL Evo a while ago. I have problems with my wrist so I bought it as a last try on dropped bars with the backup plan to change the bars to a flat bar or maybe a really flared dropped bar. Maybe in combination with a Velo Orange Cigne stem.

What I didn't realize was that it's not just to change the bars. The light switch is in the right side of the drop and the USB charger plug is in the top of the stem. All cables runs up and down inside the steerer tube down to the fork.

The previous owner had fiddled with the electricity so the USB plug doesn't work (I got a good discount on that) but I'm not bothered. I'll never use that anyways. He had also moved the rear light (when he removed the rear rack) cutting cables in the rear (that I have restored now since I use a rear rack). I'll rewire the front part as it's really messy rewired as well.

Here is what I would like to do but I'm not sure how. Feel free to tell me if it's just plain stupid :)

- Remove the USB plug
- Get a new on/of switch - installed almost anywhere but maybe just below the top tube?
- What kind of switch should I buy?
- Or if that's too hard just buy a new E3-light with the built in switch?

The specifications are:

- Supernova E3 PURE 3 front light
- Supernova E3 TAIL LIGHT 2
- Supernova The plug USB charger
- Shimano Dynamo DH-3D32-QR

Are there any other solutions or ideas?

Thanks a million and sorry the long question. I'll update here once I find a good solution for it.

Comment: Get a waterproof handlebar switch, there are a bunch of different styles available for motorcycle handlebars.

Answer (score 2):

To get a switch in your system is pretty straight forward, get one of this switches.

[image]

Make sure that you install it in the negative(common, ground, black cable, etc) lead. It's good practice and for other appliances safer. Make sure to tape everything properly and if you can, get some heatshrink wrap.

Fo the usb "The plug" I assume, just take it off as any spider cap and disconnect the terminals and take it off.

Comment: Thanks! What are those swiches? And do you put them i a box or where do you place them?

Comment: And do i just put the swich somewhere after the dynamo hub?

Comment: @Ola Yes, it should be placed between the dynamo and the bulb. You can mount it anywhere you can. I got myself a piece of metal, which i cutted and drilled to suit my needs, and mounted it on a bolt for the break levers. This was done to open a automatic gate with a remote. It was a hazzle to take off gloves and everything when i got home on motorcycle.

Comment: You can find those switches at big box hardware stores. If possible, get a *waterproof* switch. They also sell (black) heat-shrink wrap for dirt cheap. You can shrink it using a lighter. It will protect your splices from dirt/water better than electrical tape. If you need more wire, get 16 or 18 gauge wire (16 gauge is thicker, which makes it easier to work with IMO).

Answer (score 1):

What I actually turned out to do was to pull out the switch from the handlebar (it was glued with silicone) and put that in a small box that I attached under my top tube.

Seems to work fine!

Thanks for all help!